# How to replicate/simulate experiments done on dsp kit 6713 without using hardware?

Tags: dsp-core, c

Due to covid, our university is now offering online classes to under grad students, even labs are conducted online.

But we are bit confused regarding evaluation? We make videos of demonstration of dsp kit 6713 and upload them to web and share their link with students.

But question is how we can evaluate / assess learning of students especially their ability of C programming to program DSP kit and especially in starting labs experiments for example switching on/off Led using dip switches available on dsp kit 6713.

It isn't practical  to deliver each student a dsp kit at home, please recommend other solutions!

Comment: This isn't really a signal processing question, is it? However, I'd re-evaluate what you *really* want to teach, seeing that you posted this on a signal processing site: Programming can be done just as well targetting any other architecture than the TMS320C6713. Honestly, I don't think there's much value in teaching students to blink an LED on a relatively special-usecase DSP board, unless you want to teach them embedded development – which again I wouldn't recommend doing on a DSP board. If you just want to teach them how to do digital signal processing in software:

Comment: Let them do that on a PC, targetting a PC. There's not really a downside to that for undergrad students – only when they know very well how to do that, they could then move to remotely deploying code on a DSP board (and by then, DIP switches and LEDs are rather boring, and you'd use the board for something it's really meant for, like pushing through hundreds of millions of values per second). But honestly, I don't think your students learn too much on an old DSP board that they couldn't learn targetting x86_64 or ARM64 + SIMD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hardware kits for DSP Lab?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69789/hardware-kits-for-dsp-lab)

Comment: Thanks@MarcusMüller for your comments but i don't think that the question referred by you contains reasonable guidance relevant to my question

Comment: @MarcusMüller your comments and suggestions are very helpful but sorry for we have to follow curriculum/syllabus already set by our department and that is why i am trying to find help relevant to our scenario

Comment: What I found is that you really don't have to adhere 100% to the current syllabus; this is a pandemic. You have to work around that, and the department has to accept what you'll do :) The DSP thing you have is double bad, because other DSP platforms at least have software emulators that students could use at home – TMS320C67 doesn't even have that. It's really software development like in the early 90s, and that doesn't work when people have to work remotely.

Comment: your last comment is also very helpful ,but as you pointed out in your comment"other DSP platforms at least have software emulators that students could use at home – TMS320C67 doesn't even have that".  So can you please recommend any DSP platform(from TI) which has simulator available and which is some how closer/similar to TMS320C6713 ?

Comment: Oh, I could recommend the rather esoteric DSP-enhanced architecture called x86_64, for which many free tools exist. It has highly optimized fused load/condition/calculate instructions, awesome (up to 512 bit wide!!) SIMD instructions, most processors implementing it are exquisitely pipelined and its FPU instructions are often at least as fast as their integer counterparts. What about that? If you want to add some modern concurrent independent but shared memory multiprocessor DSP: they can be bought rather cheaply in chips carrying up to 32 cores!